# How to dual boot a notebook computer with windows 8.1

Tags: multi-boot

I was wondering if can dual boot with a Samsung Notebook with windows 8.1 and no disk drive, because i really want to try another OS. Thank You if you can help!

Comment: do you mean how to install an OS without having a disk drive? cause it's pretty doable with a USB drive.

Comment: @xgeorgekx Yes basicly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To try new OS you probably can use [Oracle Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/). Dual boot is previous century.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to create a bootable USB. You can use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to do it. Once done you have to restart your computer and go to your computer's boot menu and choose to boot from USB. Rest is the same as using a disk.